# chrome is undefined in chrome extension when using webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension, webpack-dev-server

I'm building a chrome extension that uses react and webpack. I need to access the chrome.* apis in the react app. This works fine when I use webpack to build the extension and then load it in the browser, but in order to speed up development I'm using webpack-dev-server to serve my app at localhost with hot module replacement. Trying to access chrome.* apis in development mode gives me an error that says chrome is undefined.

I've spent a couple days looking for a solution and all I've found is a couple chrome-extension templates on Github that also say the chrome apis don't work with webpack-dev-server.

I can access the window object, which has a chrome property on it, but none of the apis. For example, console.log(window.chrome) gives me something but window.chrome.bookmarks doesn't.

Comment: Did you find a solution?